# Pushed code in an outdated forked branch of git

Tags: git, github

I am still a bit new to git. I pushed a commit to a forked branch. Tried raising a pull request from the forked branch to the main branch. But the pull request is showing my two old commits which were already merged by the owner of the main branch.

I did do fetch and pull on forked branch before starting my work today. Why are those old commits coming up if they were merged? I need to get rid of these old commits to move ahead with a clean pull request with one new commit only. I am a bit confused. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing how you're updating your branch, you might need to add the `--rebase` flag if you're using the same branch:

```
git pull --rebase upstream master
```

This should fast-forward your branch to the latest commit on the `master` branch.

Another thing you might want to consider is changing your workflow. Instead of using the same branch, start with a fresh one off the latest `master` (or whichever target branch). If you want to use the same branch name, but know those changes have been merged to your target branch, then delete that branch and then make a new one.

```
(my-branch)$ git checkout master
(master)$ git pull upstream master
(master)$ git branch -D my-branch
(master)$ git checkout -b my-branch
(my-branch)$ // should be a fresh branch now
```

One thing to note, if you get a merge commit of "merging master into master," that means you have changes on your local `master` branch that are not on the remote's `master` branch. If you know that those changes are fine to be kept on the `master` branch, then you should use the `--rebase` flag so that it just fast-forwards your current pointer to the the latest pointer on `master` to avoid that merge commit.

This medium post seems to help explain it a little more in-depth than I did just here - https://medium.com/@mvuksano/git-tips-use-only-fast-forward-merges-with-rebase-c80c9d260a83.

Comment: Before reading your answer, without wait, I deleted the fork and forked again to start afresh just like the first time, similar to what you seem to have indicated in your second point. This worked for me. I have tried `rebase -i` once to just skip and pick commits.  I will try rebase for this purpose as well. Thanks for the link.

Comment: so when you say "delete the fork" do you mean you deleted your entire repo and recloned it? Or did you mean to say you "deleted the branch" instead? You shouldn't need to delete your fork that often, if ever. You shouldn't use `rebase -i` just to skip commits. That probably means that that branch just hasn't been rebased onto the latest HEAD of your target branch if you're skipping commits.

Comment: I deleted the forked branch, forked again and cloned the fork in a new folder. I will try rebase next time to get the changes which were merged in the target branch after my last commits. Is this the best way to sync local repo of forked branch with the target branch before raising pull requests?

Comment: You shouldn't have to "fork again" after you've forked it once and typically shouldn't have to clone it again. The _only_ time I clone again is when I've completely fubar'ed my repo AND I know all of my work is up on my remote so then when i reclone it, i have all my previous work. Ideally, your target branch is always up-to-date with your `upstream` (ie. company's fork).